# SQLAlchemy docs (setting Column defaults) - How is this line syntactically valid python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

While reading through the SQLAlchemy documentation for Column constructor arguments, I found [this code example](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/defaults.html#sql-expressions) (edited to remove unrelated calls to `Column()`, see the full example at the link):

```
t = Table("mytable", meta,
    # define 'key' to pull its default from the 'keyvalues' table
    Column('key', String(20), default=keyvalues.select(keyvalues.c.type='type1', limit=1))
)
```

Specifically, I do not understand how the `default` argument of `Column()` is valid Python. To both me and to my Python interpreter, `keyvalues.select(keyvalues.c.type='type1', limit=1)`
appears to be using the expression `keyvalues.c.type` as the name of a keyword argument to `keyvalues.select()`.

The documentation glosses over the definition of `keyvalues`, and I haven't been able to find a way of defining `keyvalues` that stops my interpreter from throwing a SyntaxError.

Am I correct that expressions cannot be used as keywords? Is this actually valid syntax for a different reason? If it is valid syntax, could you provide a short example showing the necessary code to make it valid?

Comment: The docs has a typo, it should have been `==`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a typo date back to [2006](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/commit/c5e1abc7f7adce841775ea92b72bcf95207027af), have submitted a [patch](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/pull/408) to fix.